# Where to add axios interceptors in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am building a react app. I want to redirect to login when token is expired. I can use axios interceptor to that.I add that to App.js as follows.

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {

      if (response.status === 401) {
        console.log("You are not authorized");
        //redirect
      }
      return response;
    }, (error) => {
      if (error.response && error.response.data) {
        return Promise.reject(error.response.data);
      }
      return Promise.reject(error.message);
    });
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Layout>
          <Switch>
            <PRoute path="/incident-reporting" component={Home}></PRoute>
            <RRoute exact={true} path="/" component={Login}></RRoute>
            <NFound></NFound>
          </Switch>
        </Layout>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

But it is not working as expected. I am not using hooks. I want to know where to add interceptors in reactjs.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a interceptor file and include that file when you want to use `axios`

```
import axios from 'axios';

const axiosInterceptor =  axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {

      if (response.status === 401) {
        console.log("You are not authorized");
        //redirect
      }
      return response;
    }, (error) => {
      if (error.response && error.response.data) {
        return Promise.reject(error.response.data);
      }
      return Promise.reject(error.message);
    });

export default axiosInterceptor;
```

And in your component

```
import axiosInterceptor from './utils/axiosInterceptor.js'

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

  }

  render() {

    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Layout>
          <Switch>
            <PRoute path="/incident-reporting" component={Home}></PRoute>
            <RRoute exact={true} path="/" component={Login}></RRoute>
            <NFound></NFound>
          </Switch>
        </Layout>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how to add ```axiosInterceptor``` to App.js

Comment: You can add in any file.js and import that file where you want to use axios